# How to turn off webpack linting

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: arguments is a reserved word in strict mode
```

when trying to do:

```
console.log(arguments);
```

How do I turn off webpack linting?  My config looks like so:

```
var plugins = [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        debug: true
    }),
    plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }))
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin())
];

webpack({
    entry: entry.path,
    output: {
        filename: output['file name'],
        path: output.path
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: module.paths,
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: loader.paths
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        errorDetails: true,
        modules: true,
        modulesSort: "field",
        reasons: true,
    }
}, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        require('log')(err);
        return;
    }

    const info = stats.toJson();
    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
        require('log')(info.errors);
    }
    else {
        require('log')(options.launcher + " compiled")
    }

    if (stats.hasWarnings()) {
        require('log')(info.warnings)
    }
});
```

....
Words so that I can post this questions with out stackoverflow giving me the error that my question is mostly code.... 
...

Comment: Could you also post your package.json?

Answer (score 4):

This is an **SyntaxError**, which means you have a broken code that can't be compiled. It's the same error you get when you forget to type half of a curly brackets.

It's not a lint problem (for code styles).

Most likely you mistakenly used reserved word `arguments` as a variable name. Rename it to something else.

Run code bellow you can see you still get an error without webpack.

```js
"use strict";
var arguments = 1;
console.log(arguments)
```

Comment: yea.. I had function log(arguments) { ... }.  I still loath the fact that this stopped compilation though...